# Generating SignatureValue using HMAC-SHA1 in XML

Tags: php, xml, signature, saml

The signature method is `HMAC-SHA1`, and I already have `<SignedInfo>` generated. The problem is that I am not sure what to use as the key in the HMAC calculation.

I noticed that there are two `<Entropy>` with enclosing `<BinarySecret>` from the initial request (RST) and response (RSTR). I read from WS-Trust that this indicates that I could generate a proof key using these two binary values from the `<BinarySecret>` and `PSHA1` as specified in `<ComputeKey>` tag from the response. However, I could never get the same signature value as the one in the sample from the service provider.

Any information would help!

As an example:

- The binary secret from RST is 
  `grrlUUfhuNwlvQzQ4bV6TT3wA8ieZPltIf4+H7nIvCE=`
- The binary secret from RSTR is 
  `YLABh3ZmZyiO5gvVLZe9J4JPd9w59KGeTFwE85XlzxE=`
- The correct signature value is 
  `nXJEN8p1nupMA/00TK03VZlADkU=`
- The signature value I generate is
  `bEGpeRFsznafFRf86g281zKV3Ro=`
- The content of SignInfo is as follow

> ```
> <SignedInfo>
>    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
>    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"/>
>    <Reference URI="#_0">
>     <Transforms>
>      <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
>     </Transforms>
>     <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
>     <DigestValue>CwMGnFZklO7XsDfFguzl0tw7iHM=</DigestValue>
>    </Reference>
>   </SignedInfo>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to base64 decode the values before hashing/verifying?
You can hash with sha256 without a key by using hash() by the way.